# Check the sortedness Of An Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need an Algorithm which is used to find the N-element randomly-ordered integer
array is either already sorted or not.

Comment: If you need more than a binary yes/no answer see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104166/algorithm-for-rating-the-monotonicity-of-an-array-i-e-judging-the-sortedness

Answer (score 7):

Just loop through the array til you find an element that is less than the previous one. In C/Java'ish pseudo-code:

```
int prev = array[0];
boolean sorted = true;
for (int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] < prev) {
    sorted = false;
    break;
  }
  prev = array[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Test if ascending:

```
for item i in items
    if i > nextitem
       return false

return true
```